# WPF drag & drop between containers

Tags: wpf, controls, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I've got a container, say a Grid.  It has two containers, say StackPanels.

StackPanel #1 has some rectangles.  What's the best way to enable a user to drag a rectangle and drop it in the StackPanel #2 (and have that rectangle be a child of StackPanel #2).

I've got the drag bit sussed - the only thing that's unclear is whether to actually use containers or just handle all the rectangles manually in a straight canvas.

Comment: Any updated answers? I've got the same question and am new at WPF so example code is most helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the logic behind actually moving the items goes, a `StackPanel` as a container is just fine. If you want to preview the item whilst it's being dragged, you can implement an `Adorner` that displays the `Visual` whilst it is being dragged.